# deekshya vs. gyan what's the difference

Tags: bhakti, spirituality

When I read the bhagwat geeta I not even once came across the word **deekshya** only **gyan** , but outside the geeta and on majorly other forms of attaining liberation i.e. forms different from **devotion** I also hear the word **deekshya**.

So what's the difference between **deekshya** and **gyan**, and does **deekshya** have any role in **devotion**(*bhakti*). Was the knowledge imparted by **Lord Krishna** to **Arjuna** through geeta **deekshya** or **gyan**?

Answer (score 1):

*Dīkṣā* in the context of *bhakti* means to take initiation from a guru, which is actually hinted at in Gītā 4.34 (*tad viddhi praṇipātena
paripraśnena sevayā*). Śrī Rūpa Gosvāmī lists approaching a *guru* and taking *dīkṣā* from him as the first steps into *bhakti* (*guru-pādāśrayas tasmāt kṛṣṇa-dīkṣādi-śikṣaṇam*, *Bhakti-rasāmṛta-sindhu* (1.2.74))

*Jñāna* on the other hands is usually translated as "knowledge", but has a much deeper meaning than the English term would convey

Comment: I meant for a more general differentiation than in terms of bhakti or any form.